# Solve the following Double Integral

Tags: integration

I have this double integral.

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{0}^{2}(10y)dydx/(x^2 +y^2 +100)^{3/2}$$

I was trying to substitute $y^2 = u$ then try $2ydy = du$ and proceed by putting the limits but it seems to be the wrong method

If i try to convert it to polar coordinates then,in which i will get a $r^2$ term which i dont know how to deal with.

$\int\int (10(rsin(\theta)rdrd\theta)/(r^2 +100)^{3/2} $

Please give me hint on how to go above with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct with the first substitution $$\int \frac{10 y}{\left(x^2+y^2+100\right)^{3/2}} \,dy=\int \frac{5}{\left(u+x^2+100\right)^{3/2}} \,du=-\frac{10}{\sqrt{u+x^2+100}}$$ Since for $y$ the bounds are $0$ and $2$, they become $0$ and $4$ for $u$. So $$\int_0^2 \frac{10 y}{\left(x^2+y^2+100\right)^{3/2}} \,dy=10 \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+100}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+104}}\right)$$ Now, integrate with respect to $x$.

I am sure that you can take it from here.